# Exclude files from one branch to another during pull request in GitHub?

Tags: jenkins, github, github-actions

Ho to exclude files from one branch to another during pull request in GitHub?

I created GitHub actions for CI. It created .github/workflows folder and main.yml file in that directory. 
How can exclude the file to be merged from one branch to another during the pull request/merge.

or lets says, i created Jenkinsfile and updated in the GitHub repository in that staging branch. 
How can i exclude the files during the PR/Merge from staging branch to master branch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can, and I think that even if you can - you shouldn't.

If you have different long-running branches - such as `staging` and `master` (for production), these branches should include the files for both of them - be it Jenkinsfiles or others. Name them differently and have them both be committed to both branches.

As for workflows, you can have two workflows (`.github/workflows/stage.yml` and `.github/workflows/production.yml` for example), and each of them should only be triggered when code is pushed to their respective branch:

```
on:
  push: { branches: [master] }
  pull_request: { branches: [master] }

# and

on:
  push: { branches: [stage] }
```

If I may provide another piece of advice - think if you really need these to be separate branches, and not just tags. After all, I am assuming that `staging` is always eventually merged to `master` - so its just a step towards production, and not a parallel branch. I control a wide range of different repositories, and never used long-running branches for anything.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense